# windows.onbeforeunload - Is there a way of calling a function before leave/stay?

Tags: javascript, html, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to ask the use if he really wants to leave the page where a youtube video is playing. But before asking the question "Are you sure to leave the page ?", I want to pause the video.
I try with this code (instead of pause the video I just write something in a div), but the content of the div only changes after the user decided to stay on the page...Is there a way to fix it ?

```
    <script>
        var confirmOnLeave = function(msg) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {          

                e = e || window.event;
                msg = msg || '';
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'stop'; 
                // For IE and Firefox
                if (e) {e.returnValue = msg;}

                // For Chrome and Safari
                return msg;
            };

        };
        confirmOnLeave('Are you sure to leave the page ?');
    </script>
   <body>
    <div id='test'> a </div>
    </body>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Yrs47/

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope -- "works as designed."

Back in the day, a lot of websites would abuse `onbeforeunload` to do things like -- reload the current page, open up a slew of pop-unders or just cancel the navigate away.

Now -- there is a semi-controllable action that you *can* do.  Using Javascript, you can connect to every `link` on the page and open your dialogue box and ask what they'd like to do.  That may catch some of your needs, but it wouldn't catch people opening a bookmark, clicking the `back` button or typing in a new URL.